# Вернутся в предыдущие меню (консоль)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, циклы

Программа имеет такую структуру.
Как мне после отработки  функции `Hello` запустить опять функцию `menu`?

```
void Hello(){
    cout<<"Hello";

cout>>i;

switch(i){
case 1: ;break;
  }

}

void menu(){
cout<<"Enter number";

cin>>i;

switch(i){
    case 1:Hello();break;
    }
};

int main(){

menu();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить в нее цикл.

```
void menu()
{
    for(;;) 
    {
        cout<<"Enter number";
        cin>>i;

        switch(i){
            case 1:Hello();break;
        }
    }
}
```

И в `switch` - выход из функции по какому-то вводу специально для выхода.